# css - sidebar - background image with fixed positioning

Tags: html, css

I have a standard template for one of my sites which i am developing, this template is one standard page with a removable left side bar.

This is the page:

[image]

However as the user scrolls to the bottom:

[image]

I've used a border so you can see the bottom of the page.

I cannot seem to find the class that is causing this or not fixing this if you see what I mean.

This is a link to the site:

[https://accounts.dpwebdev.co.uk/dashboard/](https://accounts.dpwebdev.co.uk/dashboard.php)

Any Ideas would be gratefully received.

Thanks

Comment: Open google chromes developer console, go to the Elements section and find the problematic section. Click on that div in the elements menu and on the right it will show you what classes the styles are coming from. The console is also available in all the major browsers.

Comment: It helps if you edit your question and add a short but working example. That way, once you fix the linked site, this question will still be useful to future users.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Between `maincontainer` and `cboxOverlay` you have some spaces.

Just remove them.

Or you can add

```
.sidebar_inner{
   background-color:#F1F1F1;
}
```

Comment: The spaces are being produced by a script and I cannot remove them.

Thanks for the alternative :)

Comment: I think you mean `background-color:#F1F1F1;`